# Issue with Twitter and Meteor

Tags: meteor

I get the following error with Meteor (version 0.6.6.3) and clicking on the sign in button for Twitter.

```
I2038-06:13:28.670(-8)? Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Failed to send OAuth1 request to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token. failed [401] Failed to validate oauth signature and token
I2038-06:13:28.673(-8)?     at OAuth1Binding._call (packages/oauth1/oauth1_binding.js:143)
I2038-06:13:28.674(-8)?     at OAuth1Binding.prepareRequestToken (packages/oauth1/oauth1_binding.js:27)
I2038-06:13:28.675(-8)?     at Oauth._requestHandlers.(anonymous function) (packages/oauth1/oauth1_server.js:21)
I2038-06:13:28.676(-8)?     at middleware (packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:105)
I2038-06:13:28.677(-8)?     at packages/oauth/oauth_server.js:78
```

Anybody has an idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so after poking around for a while I finally made it work. Here's the workaround I found that could hopefully help others who get a similar error.

**Setup**

- A local debian server running meteor, with IP address 192.168.2.100. Could be a virtualbox like in my case.
- You are accessing the meteor app with your navigator on
  192.168.2.100:3000 from your Windows computer
- Connecting through the Twitter package does not work

**Solution**

- In you windows host file setup your localhost as 192.168.2.100 instead of 127.0.0.1
- In the Twitter app configuration enter for the callback `http://192.168.2.100:3000/_oauth/twitter?close`
- You may have to wait or restart from scratch

Comment: Related and helpful (auth using Meteor + Twitter with images) http://meteor.hromnik.com/blog/login-with-facebook-twitter-and-google-in-meteor

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue caused by manually removing and inserting the loginServiceConfiguration incorrectly. If you're not using the configuration tool, make sure you're inserting a `consumerKey` rather than `clientId`.

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.remove({
  service: "twitter"
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
  service: "twitter",
  consumerKey: "...",
  secret: "..."
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but my configuration seems correct. I have the right fields. I've deleted the collectin and went through the configuration a couple of times but that didn't help.

Comment: Thank you very much for this piece of information. It was exactly what I was missing.